# why is there no display of subject/date for received emails in outlook2010?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

My husband has a computer at work, but has absolutely no knowledge of computers.  He is set up with Outlook 2010 for email and the window does not display the subject or date of his received messages.  There is no one on the grounds to help him and I am not allowed into the building.  Also, I have an iMac here so it is hard to tutor him by phone with nothing to look at.  Could you give me some help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You should get these back with Field Chooser.

http://www.officetooltips.com/outlook/tips/adding_and_removing_columns.html